# Remove files when downloading a dependency with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I am sure I once read it somewhere but I cannot find it anymore anywhere, DAMN!

So basically what I am trying to do is to specify some exclusion criteria in my composer.json file for a certain library of mine so that, when used as a dependency of a project, the importing project does not get test files, .git folders, READ.md files and all that stuff (totally useless when you only want a library as a dependency and not for development).

So basically I am trying to lighten up my libs when they are downloaded as dependencies. Anyone on that?

Ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `.gitattributes` file to your project root, looking something like this:

```
/Tests export-ignore
READ.md export-ignore
```

When someone installs your dependency this files will be excluded from the distribution zip.
There are some prerequisites for your lib to be downloaded as a zip by composer

- You need to have a stable tagged version. `dev-master` will always be cloned by composer.
- If the user installs with `composer install --prefer-source` composer will also clone from your git repo.

In all other cases composer will download the zip and all the files in `.gitattributes` will be excluded from it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a unix-like system, you can do this in one cmd, simply cd to vendor dir and :

```
find . -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*\/(tests?|docs?|\.git)" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

adapt the regex to your needs

find cmd:
http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find

regards